# overriding viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange needs super to be called?

Tags: ios, ios11, safearealayoutguide

If I override the `UIViewController`'s func `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange` do I need to call super?

```
override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()
    // do my stuff
}
```

I know that if you override `func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` and you are not calling the `super` inside, your app might behave erratically. Apple in fact says that you must call `super` at some point. I guess that is not the case here, and that's what I wanted to confirm!

Answer (score 5):

It's not required, but generally considered a best practice to call `super` on overridden methods unless there's an explicit reason not to.

If you decide that your view controller should inherit from a custom `UIViewController` subclass in the future, you won't have to make any code changes to run the superclass's implementation in each subclass.

Comment: I know that is best practice to do so, but if you override `func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` and you are not calling the `super` inside, your app might behave erratically. Apple in fact says that you must call `super` at some point. **I guess that is not the case here, and that's what I wanted to confirm!** :)